# Is this MessageDigest wrapper thread-safe?

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety, immutability

I wrote my own simplified `MessageDigest` wrapper and now I'm wondering if it's thread safe.

```
public final class SimpleIMD implements ImmutableMessageDigest {
    private final MessageDigest md;

    public SimpleIMD(MessageDigest md) {
        this.md = this.cloneMessageDigest(md);
    }

    private MessageDigest cloneMessageDigest(MessageDigest original) {
        MessageDigest clone = null;
        try {
            clone = (MessageDigest) original.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException cnse) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                "Failed to instantiate a new SimpleImd instance.",
                cnse
            );
        } finally {
            return clone;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] digest() {
        return this.md.digest();
    }

    @Override
    public ImmutableMessageDigest update(byte[] arr, int offset, int len) {
        MessageDigest newMsgDigest = this.cloneMessageDigest(this.md);
        newMsgDigest.update(arr, offset, len);
        return new SimpleIMD(newMsgDigest);
    }
}
```

Comment: The class seems to be _immutable_ and hence thread-safe. However, it doesn't automatically mean that the code _using_ the class is thread-safe.

Comment: Well, if `MessageDigest.digest` is not thread-safe, then the code isn't either. No mention of thread-safety in the Javadoc, so the safest assumption is that your code is broken. It's just an assumption however, and has to be checked

Comment: @MickMnemonic I think I need to perform digest on a fresh copy to be on the safe side. But still... what if something strange happens while cloning? It's not really atomic and I fear I need a lock somewhere.

Comment: @Dici No, [MessageDigest](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) isn't thread-safe.

Comment: @JanezKuhar, how is the `MessageDigest` you pass to the constructor used _elsewhere_ in the code? I think your thread-safety issue depends solely on that question.

Comment: @MickMnemonic That fortunately doesn't matter since it's deep-copied in. And I am only interested in thread-safety regarding `SimpleIMD` objects alone, e.g. about concurrent calls to `digest()` and `update()`.

Comment: Yes, I think it doesn't matter if this class is simply a wrapper around the passed in `MessageDigest`. If that `MessageDigest` object is not used anywhere else, I don't see what could go wrong with cloning (or why you'd need to clone in the first place). Alternatively, you could [just create a new instance each time you need one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554998/need-thread-safe-messagedigest-in-java).

Comment: @MickMnemonic I agree, the question is more theoretical.

Comment: In my opinion as long as the underlying object is not thread-safe and that we expose a `digest` method which directly delegates the call to the underlying object, then the code is not thread-safe unless `digest` has no side-effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suspected, my code wasn't thread safe.

For example, if 2 threads shared the same `SimpleIMD` object and the order of method invocations in time would go something like this:

```
  T1                 T2
  |                  |
update()             |
  |                  |
  |                digest()
  |                  |
  |                  |
  |                  |
```

then there is no guarantee that `update()` will finish before `digest()`.

In fact, `digest()` may even reset the underlying `MessageDigest` instance before  `update()`  and `T1` will have the wrong hash. This problem can be solved by performing `digest()` on a fresh copy.

So the method:

```
@Override
public byte[] digest() {
    return this.md.digest();
}
```

has to be changed to:

```
@Override
public byte[] digest() {
    return this.cloneMessageDigest(this.md).digest();
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

The solution presented here is incorporated into [`ImmutableMessageDigest`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.github.glusk/caesar/latest/com.github.glusk.caesar/com/github/glusk/caesar/hashing/ImmutableMessageDigest.html) that's part of [Caesar](https://github.com/Glusk/caesar), an open source library I wrote.